# Manejo de Transacciones en SqlServer y vb.net con TransactionScope

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, transacciones

```
 Using tran As New Transactions.TransactionScope
            Try
                InsertaEnTabla1()
                InsertaEnTabla2()
                InsertaEnTabla3()
                tran.Complete()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
    End Using
```

Estoy utilizando este procedimiento para el manejo de transacciones en sqlserver, 
la cuestión es que aun cuando no se ejecuta el tran.complete, aplica lo ejecutado en los procedimientos anteriores, es decir si hay una excepción en   InsertaEnTabla3(), lo que guarde en   InsertaEnTabla1() y   InsertaEnTabla2() queda almacenado, no hace Rollback...

Comment: Hola avargasma. ¿Encontraste solución a tu problema? Si no, te sugiero de modificar el código en tu pregunta para que se conforme a lo que es [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Pero, en efecto, a primera vista, pareciera que tu código debería funcionar correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema viene por el lado del Try.

```
 Try 
   Using tran As New Transactions.TransactionScope
            InsertaEnTabla1()
            InsertaEnTabla2()
            InsertaEnTabla3()
            tran.Complete()
   End Using
 Catch ex As TransactionAbortedException
    writer.WriteLine("TransactionAbortedException Message: {0}", ex.Message)
 Catch ex As ApplicationException
    writer.WriteLine("ApplicationException Message: {0}", ex.Message)
 End Try
```

Así y todo deberías utilizar los códigos que están dentro de "InsertaEnTabla1" dentro del Using.